# Do I need to use SAML and JWT for auth in SSO web app?

Tags: jwt, saml, node.js

I am new to SAML authentication process so I am just trying to figure out if I understand it so I can try to integrate my web app (Angular/Nodejs) to an existing portal that currently uses SAML as means of authentication.

Once a user logs into the portal the IdP will have authenticated the user, so when they click a link into my web app (which has been configured as an SP) what is supposed to happen? Will the request automatically call out to IdP (or do I need to do this myself) and does it send back a SAML response to my new app? Should I then verify the response etc.. and then also generate a JWT token which is then attached to every subsequent request to my web app? 
Can SAML provide this? or is just for SSO?

Would really appreciate an explanation on how it should all hang together.

Comment: Since this question was asked, Apress has published a highly relevant book: https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484250945 .